# Set a past date for debug log tracking?

Tags: debug

I want to check a workflow name using debug logs as a result I am unable to set the criteria for debug logs. I want to fetch a data for a user for 10th March,2017 but getting an error that expiration date must be in future.

[image]

Comment: image is not displaying

Comment: Debug logs must be set to be captured prior to the event you want to monitor. You cannot go back in time.

Comment: If you want to see the past event, is there any other way we can see through any other tools?

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce only keeps track of general debug statistics, such as execution time, memory used, Internal Server Errors, and so on. To get *detailed* logs, you have to request them in advance. Once a transaction has completed, the logs for that transaction are discarded if no "trace flags" have been set on the user, and you can never get them back. For this reason, salesforce requires that debug logs start from a given request time to an end time that is in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You are only allowed to set up a `Trace Flag` with an `Expiration Date` some time between the `Start Date` and 24 hours from that value (or now if `Start Date` is blank).

- If you try to create a `Trace Flag` with no `Start Date` that expires in the past, you should get an exception:

  > Error: ExpirationDate must be in the future.
- If you try to create a `Trace Flag` whose `Expiration Date` is before its `Start Date`, you should get this exception:

  > Error: When StartDate and ExpirationDate are not null, ExpirationDate must be after StartDate.
- If you try to set a Trace Flag for a range of more than 24 hours, you should get this exception:

  > Error: Trace flags can be active for up to 24 hours. Set ExpirationDate to be less than 24 hours from StartDate, or, if StartDate is null, less than 24 hours from now.